# How can I trigger a function to multiple spreadsheets from a single script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have to develop a spreadsheet for each department within a company (around 60 in total), all of those have to be identical and are going to populate a master spreadsheet. I have a similar case in which the function triggers when a user inputs data as an onEdit(e) function trigger. The problem is, that those "backend" sheets (which are hidden and protected) only can be triggered by me manually.

Due to the nature of the first project I mentioned, I need to trigger some functions on those 60 spreadsheets and their respective sheets in order to push updates to all of them as I keep developing and improving the structure and calculations. Those functions might be destined to set Formulas, read and write data, etc.

I know how to link scripts files as a library, the developer mode, etc, but I ignore how to trigger a function in multiple places from a single one. Any help or hint would be great guys :)

Love y'all

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: @ross Only what's within my knowledge which is linking as many spreadsheets as needed to a single script file, I don't have quite a lot of experience programming, it actually works! but only when a sheet is edited manually, so that in order to get the updates I have to open all the documents and all the sheets, edit or update the page (since I also set an onOpen(e) function) and that's it, but, it's not affordable to keep doing that at a larger scale. :/

Comment: Couple of things ... 1) does [Google Apps Script Project Trigger Is Not Visible Across Shared Users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51627479/1330560) offer any ideas. Also an interesting comment by Felipe Hoffa from Google. 2) 60 identical spreadsheets, etc - there IS a point where a spreadsheet runs out of steam 3) are you running GSuite or plain Google docs?

Comment: @Tedinoz 1) let me check that out 2) yes, eventually those sheets are going to be considered as finished and I wont't have to push updates anymore, but the fact is that I have to deliver them asap in order to start harvesting data from quite a lot of people and keep developing that system while it happens 3) Gsuite :D

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any way to activate triggers from a script. Some workaround ideas you could implement are these:

1) Instead of using an onEdit trigger in each spreadsheet you could use a Clock trigger [1] which is an Installable trigger [2]. This way the functions could get activated at a certain time or every certain time.

2) Put all the scripts together in a single script. You can use the openById() function [3] to obtain and manipulate the different spreadsheets.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)

Comment: Ok! I'm gonna give it a try, I'll let you know what I can achieve! thanks!